# How to make a checkbox non-editable in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I have a checkbox. I will obtain one value from a database to determine whether the checkbox can be edited or not. If this value is zero, the checkbox should not be selected. How do I achieve that in code? Please help me out here. This is my code:

```
String status = "0"; // (obtained from the database)
if(status)
{
    // should not be editable - can't be selected.
} else {
    // can be selected.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If this is REALLY what you want to do instead of using a JLabel with appropriate text and/or icon, you can create an action listener for the checkbox and have it call setSelected:

```
// the action listener for the checkbox
private void myCheckBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    if (status.equals("0")
        myCheckBox.setSelected(false);
    else
        myCheckBox.setSelected(true);
}
```

To say the least, this isn't an elegant solution, but it does give the appearance that the checkbox isn't editable.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`setEnabled`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) method for that.

Comment: Unfortunately that also ghosts the checkbox, making it less visible